# sharepoint 365 - Implementing responsive design

Tags: responsive

I Implemented jQuery responsive carousel. 
On pure HTML page its working fine but with SharePoint aspx page is not working. it is not behaving responsively.I assume that it relate to SharePoint styles.

what is the right approach to implement responsive design in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the console if you get the width undefined error then you div alignment is not proper. Your missing div alignments. Make sure you do not miss anything, it should work fine as i have implemented many a times

Comment: I noticed that elemnt #contentBox has property min-width:703px (core15.css). If I override it, im getting the responsive behavior. Am I right?